# Is there any way to generate html link from a select tag option list value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Suppose I have a file "file.html" with the content:

```
<select>
  <option vale="apple.html">Apple</option>
  <option vale="ball.html">Ball</option>
  <option vale="cat.html">Cat</option>
</select>
```

Now I want the value and the names of each option tag from this file to be displayed in another file "new.html" as:

```
<a href="apple.html">Apple</a>
<a href="ball.html">Ball</a>
<a href="cat.html">Cat</a>
```

What will be the best possible way of achieving this? and also this must be dynamic so that in adding a new option tag in "file.html",the value and names of that updated option tag is displayed automatically in new.html.
My whole intention is to maintain one common file to obtain the select option list and the html links separately from that one common file.Changing the data in that one common file will trigger the change in option list and the html link in different files automatically.In this case that one common is the "file.html".

Any advice on how to achieve the result a different way is also welcomed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually I don't know where to start!

Comment: Need more clarification on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want an option list in one file and a html link in another file from one common list of data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage to store each link and access it to other page.

Use JQuery library to make life easier.

Use this as reference:

On your file.html

```
  <select id="linkList">
    <option value="facebook.com" >Facebook</option>
    <option value="google.com" >Google</option>
    <option value="yahoo.com" >Yahoo</option>
  </select>
```

On your new.html

```
  <div id="links">

  </div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var linkList = [];
      $('select#linkList').children('option').each(function(i,v){
        linkList.push( $(this)[0].value );
      });
      localStorage.setItem( 'linkList', linkList );
      var links = localStorage.getItem( 'linkList' );
      var linksArray = links.split(',');
      var template = '';
      var link = linksArray.map(function(value, index){
        return '<a href="http://www.'+value+'">'+value.replace('.com','').toUpperCase()+'</a><br/>';
      });
      $('#links').html(link);
      //console.log(linksArray);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if possible, give a snapshot of your current implementation

Comment: Here is brief,in "new.html" file the head section contains the link to ajax google api,followed by the jquery code you provide under different <script></script> tag.The body contains the  "<div id="links">  </div>" that's all.Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: try consoling localstorage.. let's see if there's data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without any database where you load the list from. Maybe it is possible to make one file with all the options and include this file in the files where you want to use it. With this option you only have to change one file to change every other file.

Answer (score 0):

The most ideal way in which such things are done is by setting up a database and having the values stored in the database. You can also later have a functionality to update the values from your website.

If you won't be using a database you can actually store your list of values into an xml or json file and then use ajax in jquery to load the information and set it into your html. 
You can look into this link on how ajax will work http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Once you have the data, the jquery to update your html will look something like this.

```
mydata.forEach(
    function(s){
        $("select").append($("<option>").attr("value", s).text(s));
    }
);
```

Where `mydata` is your array of data. 
Of course the code will need several updates such as setting an id for your select. However this is the basic idea.

Comment: Which will be faster loading data from the database or from the XML file?

Comment: that depends on the amount of data. database is designed to handle a large amount of data. But considering that a database is normally on a different server, for small amounts of data it will surely be faster to have a local file than connecting and getting a response from a database

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can use this sample:

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .link-item {
                display: block;
                min-width: 100px;
                margin-top: 15px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select class="target-combo">
          <option value="apple.html">Apple</option>
          <option value="ball.html">Ball</option>
          <option value="cat.html">Cat</option>
        </select>
        <select class="target-combo">
          <option value="apple.html">Apple2</option>
          <option value="ball.html">Ball3</option>
          <option value="cat.html">Cat3</option>

        </select>
        <div id="linksWrapper"></div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var comBoOptions = $("select.target-combo").children("option");

                var links = [];
                comBoOptions.each(function() {
                    links.push("<a href='" + $(this).val() + "' class='link-item' >" + $(this).text() + "</a>");
                });

                $("#linksWrapper").html(links.join(""));

            })

        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option value="apple.html">Apple</option>
  <option value="ball.html">Ball</option>
  <option value="cat.html">Cat</option>
</select>
```